# Recursive Types alias in typescript - typing flatten function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-level-computation

So I've been trying, for fun and for educative purpose, to write a type-level Flatten function.
Here is what I've got so far :

```js
type List<Head, Tail extends Array<Head>> =
  ((h: Head, ...args: Tail) => any) extends ((...args: infer Arr) => any) ? Arr : never

type Head<Arr extends Array<any>> =
  ((...args: Arr) => any) extends ((h: infer Head, ...t: Array<any>) => any) ? Head : never

type Tail<Arr extends Array<any>> =
  ((...args: Arr) => any) extends ((h: any, ...t: infer Tail) => any) ? Tail : never

type HasTail<Arr extends Array<any>> =
  ((...args: Arr) => any) extends ((h: any, ...t: infer Tail) => any)
    ? Tail extends []
      ? false
      : true
    : false

type Flatten<Arr extends Array<Array<any>>> =
Arr extends []
  ? []
  : HasTail<Arr> extends true
    ? List<Head<Head<Arr>>, Flatten<Tail<Arr>>>
    : Head<Arr>
```

It's not perfect as it does not check enough details on the input `Arr` but it's a good start I think. My problem is that I receive a `Type alias 'Flatten' circularly references itself.` error.

I thought it was fixed by this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050
Maybe I do not understand the error in the right way? Can someone explain my mistake please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, If anyone ever find stuck like this, I would recommend reading the PR's discussions I mentioned in the question.

The answer is that even if the recursion in types is allowed it's only in a subset of cases. Namely when using a "true" type in recursion. For example:

```
interface Recurse<T> {}

type Do<I> = "string" | Recurse<Do<I>>
```

That's just a simple example but it shows the idea. The call to `Do<I>` is ok if it's passed to `Recurse` only because `Recuse` is an interface. It would have work with Array, Tuple or structural types too.

For example on how to do this right, look at this libary.
https://github.com/pirix-gh/ts-toolbelt